# How to checked checkbox after selecting selectpicker option?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5

I am new in jquery. I have done half of work. But I am not find any solution. [image]

Here you see the image There are four Checkboxes Nail, Hair, Skin-care, Massage. I want when user click on Salon, Mobile beautician and Both above Nail checkbox would be ticked and when user click on Select your service Nail checkbox would be unchecked so this applies to all. I have done that but problem is that when I do select the item second time from nails the checkbox is not checked. Its working only one time. Please help me. Here I have code:-

Html:-

```
<div class="one-row">
    <?php foreach ($services as $key => $allservices) {
        if ($key <= 3) {
            if (!empty($data['services'])) {
                if (in_array($allservices['id'], $data['services'])) {
                    $checked = "checked";
                } else {
                    $checked = "";
                }
            } else {
                $checked = "";
            } ?>
            <div class="div_img_part-2">
      <span class="img_part_class-2"><img src="{{ asset('images/ServiceImages/'. $allservices['image'])}}">
                </span>
                <span class="text_part_class-2">
                     <p class="custom-checkbox firstpart">
                         <input class="firstdisable" type="checkbox" id="{{ $key }}" name="services[]"
                                value="{{ $allservices['id'] }}" <?= $checked; ?>/>
                         <label for="{{ $key }}">{{$allservices['name']}}</label>
                     /p>
                </span>
                </span>
                <select name="service_type[<?php echo $allservices['name']; ?>]" class="selectpicker">
                    <option value="">Select Your Sevice</option>
                    <option value="Salon" <?php if (!empty($data['service_type'][$allservices['name']])) {
                        if ($data['service_type'][$allservices['name']] == "Salon") { ?> selected
                        <?php }
                    } ?> >Salon
                    </option>
                    <option value="Mobile beautician" <?php if (!empty($data['service_type'][$allservices['name']])) {
                        if ($data['service_type'][$allservices['name']] == "Mobile beautician") { ?> selected
                        <?php }
                    } ?> >Mobile beautician
                    </option>
                    <option value="Both" <?php if (!empty($data['service_type'][$allservices['name']])) {
                        if ($data['service_type'][$allservices['name']] == "Both") { ?> selected
                        <?php }
                    } ?>>Both
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        <?php }
    } ?>
</div>
```

I am using Laravel framework
here is my jQuery code:-

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
$(".selectpicker").on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).parents(".div_img_part-2").find(".selectpicker").val();
    alert(value);
    if (value == "") {
        $(this).parents(".div_img_part-2").find("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', false);
        if ($("input:checked").length == 0) {
            $('.disable').prop('disabled', false);
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
    } else {
        $(this).parents(".div_img_part-2").find("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Use .prop() instead of attr() to check /uncheck your checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use closest() and prop() instead of parent() and attr().

try this :

```
$(".selectpicker").on('change', function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == "") {
        $(this).closest(".div_img_part-2").find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
        if ($("input:checked").length == 0) {
            $('.disable').prop('disabled', false);
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
    } else {
        $(this).closest(".div_img_part-2").find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```